# How to make android faster on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I have a pc with ubuntu 14.04,the configuration is:

```
CPU:Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8 
Memory:16GB
```

A server with ubuntu-14.04-server,the configuration is:

```
CPU:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2603 v2 @ 1.80GHz x 4
Memory:32GB
```

And I was trying to make Android by the following command:

```
make -j
```

Then the computer halt...
So how to specify the value of 'j' to ensure making fastest?
I suppose the value should be the numbers of cpu's processors...

Answer (score 0):

`make -j` launches as many jobs in parallel as the build dependencies allow - in the kernel build case that's way too many for most consumer class machines, the system becomes barely responsive and eventually runs out of PIDs or memory.

You need to add a number to that -j. Which brings you to this Q&A:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208568/how-to-determine-the-maximum-number-to-pass-to-make-j-option

If you want to go into fine tuning you might find the BuildIn tool useful (disclaimer - I'm the author): https://apartsw-buildin.appspot.com/